# How to change wave texture mathematically?

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural, mathematics

I want to achive this result for my column without using additional modeling (just shading and procedural textures, sorry for bad quality, I don't have better one):

[image: result]

For now I have this material (the top part for contour and the bottom part for spiral):
[image: material]
But I have a two problems:

1. for now it looks too flat even with the bump node connected to normals;
2. I can't find a math function to make the spiral to look more realistic: it should have not the straight angle, but something like this in every coil:

[image]
Can I solve that problems with math, or I should use something else? Does exist a best way to achive the final result with variations, because I think it's too much for me to use math for shapes like this (without additional geometry):

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the end-purpose of your models? e.g. Lo-poly for games.. expensive for a scenic still,,,,

Comment: @RobinBetts do you mean math is expensive for scenic? I want to create scene in Blender and than recreate it in ue5.

Comment: If for a game, you will probably want to bake to textures anyhow? So whether you make this with shader displacement or geometry is up to you, whatever you find easiest.

Comment: @RobinBetts yes, you're right, but I didn't think so far ahead :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one route to barley-sugar moulding:

[image]

.. here, including the edge-piping, although, for generality, that's probably better stripped out as a separate group. This starts out assuming your panel is UV mapped, 0-1 in U.

The strategy is distance-to-0 (a circle), but in sheared UV cells. (Giving tilted ellipses.) The distances in that masked section and the outer piping are then mapped using color-ramps to give rounded height-profiles.

This is the sort of result when used as displacement:

[image]

The other patterns you refer to are also possible, but really a separate question? Different answers may come up with different approaches.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I can't recreate that material. My displacement node output looks the same as your but with principled bsdf connected to material output I can't see anything. I checked it 3 times and the only difference I can find is in the material displacement settings. There is a "reroute" option I can't find.

Comment: Maybe share a problematic sample on https://blend-exchange.com/ ? I'll have a look.. it could be so many things.. :)

Comment: here, I upload file (https://blend-exchange.com/b/m7E64lLG/). Strange thing, I tried to create test file and recreated material - everything works fine. But in my base file it doesn't work.

Comment: @Сергей The differences are numerous: Your material is set to _Bump Only_, Robin's is set to _Displacement Only_. Your plane has no geometry to be displaced, it's only the four corner vertices. But that wouldn't matter if you would use _Adaptive Subdivision_, but your model has no _Subdivision Surface_ modifier. Even then it wouldn't work, because your settings use the _Feature Set_ "Supported" while Robin uses "Experimental". To be fair, that's too much for a beginner to realize from the answer. I would recommend searching for tutorials on "microdisplacement" for the basic understanding.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thank you, I've tried to change "Bump Only" to "bump and Displacement" or "displacement only" without result anyway. I forgot about needed geometry for displacement. So, it's almost correct answer, but I asked about solution without additional geometry. But answer is still cool because we just need to replace displacement node with bump node and connect normals to principled bsdf. And change settings to "bump only". That's all. So that's still right answer with that note.

Comment: @Сергей Read my comment again. I said you wouldn't need additional geometry if you would use _Adaptive Subdivision_ which is only available in the "Experimental" feature set, but that's not explained in the answer. That's why I suggested you watch tutorials on it to get a more in-depth understanding of what this is all about.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Oh, wow, thanks so much for covering my AFK! Maybe I should have included a how-to for displacement? But was focusing on the central issue.

Comment: @Сергей I hope you got it working this way, just so you know you can. But if your final objective is the artwork, for a game, then really I would be baking height-maps from assembled geometry. You get so much more flexibility. The topology doesn't have to be any good, you can jumble any old bits and pieces together, and shoot a depth-map from above, to use as an image texture.

Comment: Thank you all, guys! I think I'm not ready to use experimental feature set but I'm really grateful for such expanded answer and comments.

Comment: @Сергей If you are planning to use it in UE5 this wouldn't work there anyway.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann do you mean bump node? Or math? Or everything?)

Comment: @Сергей Bump nodes, Math nodes, Color Ramps... (almost) everything

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann don't agree, in ue5 you have bump offset, you can emulate color ramp (there are many tutorials and examples), you have a lot of math nodes even with custom functions. Of course, I don't know something probably, but I'm sure there is nothing impossible

Comment: @Сергей I never said there are no ways to reproduce it - but you cannot export the material setup from Blender and import it in UE. I can reproduce Blender Math node setups in Excel, that doesn't mean I can import them.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann oh, that's what you mean... I know that. I thought you mean I can't reproduce that effect in ue5)